# Submitting hcaptcha captcha token to Discord to create account using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, discord, captcha, hcaptcha

I am using python selenium to create a Discord account (https://discord.com/register), but it is protected with a hcaptcha. I have a captcha API (2captcha/capmonster) to return a captcha token and putting it into the g-captcha-response textarea. Normally there is a submit button that you would click afterwards which would then allow you to the site (if the captcha token is correct), but Discord automatically redirects you once you manually complete the hcaptcha. I am assuming that Discord is using the hcaptcha callback function. but I have had no luck finding the callback function so I can call it once I put in the captcha token.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import random
import requests
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


email = "example@gmail.com"
username = "exampleusername"
password = "examplepassword"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://discord.com/register')
WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='email']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys(email) # email
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys(username) # username
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys(password) # password
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div').click()

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(str(random.randint(1, 12))) # Month
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
actions.send_keys(str(random.randint(1, 28))) # Day
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
actions.send_keys(str(random.randint(1989, 2000))) # Year
actions.perform()

try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('inputDefault-3JxKJ2').click()  # Agree to terms and conditions
except:
    pass
driver.find_element_by_class_name('button-3k0cO7').click()  # Submit button


# get captcha key
site_key = 'f5561ba9-8f1e-40ca-9b5b-a0b3f719ef34'
url = "https://discordapp.com/register"
API_KEY = "CAPMONSTER API KEY"
s = requests.Session()
data_post = {
    "clientKey": API_KEY,
    "task":
        {
            "type": "HCaptchaTaskProxyless",
            "websiteURL": url,
            "websiteKey": site_key
        }
}
captcha_id = s.post("https://api.capmonster.cloud/createTask", json=data_post).json()
data_get = {
    "clientKey": API_KEY,
    "taskId": captcha_id['taskId']
}
captcha_answer = s.get("https://api.capmonster.cloud/getTaskResult", json=data_get).json()
while captcha_answer['status'] == "processing":
    time.sleep(5)
    captcha_answer = s.get("https://api.capmonster.cloud/getTaskResult", json=data_get).json()
captcha_token = captcha_answer["solution"]["gRecaptchaResponse"]
driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByName("g-recaptcha-response")[0].innerText="{captcha_token}";') # put captcha token into g-recaptcha-response textarea
driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByName("h-captcha-response")[0].innerText="{captcha_token}";')

# code to submit captcha token
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the network monitor on your browser to look for the callback?

Comment: I don't understand how to do this

Answer (score 2):

You should try to solve the captcha manually and see what's the difference, notice any change to the elements?

Injecting the captcha token into h-captcha-response & g-recaptcha-response elements always throws errors.

I will give you an example, sometimes a new hidden element is generated after solving the hCaptcha so what you can do is to create the exact same element

```
js_script = f"""
          let captchaElement = document.getElementById('captcha')
          let inputElement = document.createElement('input');
          inputElement.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
          inputElement.setAttribute('name', 'response_token');
          inputElement.setAttribute('value', "{captcha_token}");
          captchaElement.appendChild(inputElement)
"""
self.driver.execute_script(js_script)
```